# client.get_user(user_id) returns "user" not "member"

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
person = client.get_user(myid)
role = get(person.guild.roles, name = "rolename")
```

client:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 28, in on_message
    role = get(person.guild.roles, name = "rolename")
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

I have tried using intents, not using intents and neither return a Member object. Is there any way people know of to make `client.get_user()` to return a member rather than a user

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need a Guild object before you can get a Member object.

Comment: I think it makes sense, you're using `get_user` it's logic that it will return a `discord.User` instance, you can get a member instance with `Guild.get_member`, but you first need a `discord.Guild` instance, to get it you can use the `client.get_guild` method

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński `Guild = client.get_guild`
`person = Guild.get_member(269929037533675540)`
Returns `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_member'`

Comment: You need to call get_guild and actually pass the guild ID into it, read the docs

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński
`Guild = client.get_guild(id)`
`person = Guild.get_member(myid)`
`role = get(person.roles, name = "rolename")`
`    role = get(person.roles, name = "rolename")`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'`

Comment: did you enable intents.members? Also, why don’t you use guild.roles?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I did `intents.members = True` but now
`File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 664, in add_roles`
    `await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Ok I updated it to find the role using `id` rather than `name` and it works great. Sorry for the annoyance

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the Guild version of the user (discord.Member).
You're trying to get the roles of the user, If you use `get_user` or `fetch_user`, it's going to get the user via the bot therefore you won't have the roles from a specific user.

Here is a way you can get the list of roles that the user has with `discord.utils`.

```py
guild = message.guild
person = get(guild.users, id=myid)

role = get(guild.roles, name="rolename")

if role in person.roles: # This is what happens if the user has the role.
 ...

else: # This is what happens if the user doesn't have the role.
 ...
```

Hope this helped Have a nice day!